# Cloning arrayList in java using constructor

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I am learning Java from Udemy and the instructor wrote the following code...

Here theatre.seat is an arrayList of Seat object which is inner class of Theatre class. seatCopy is copy of theatre.seats obtained by passing theatre.seats in it's constructor. pritnList is just for printing list on the console.

```
List<Theatre.Seat> seatCopy = new ArrayList<>(theatre.seats);

Collections.shuffle(seatCopy);
System.out.println("Printing seat copy : ");
printList(seatCopy);
System.out.println("Printing theatre.seat : ");
printList(theatre.seats);
```

As this is a shallow copy i.e. both seatCopy and theatre.seats are both referencing the same arrayList object then when shuffle method is called on seatCopy, shouldn't both of the lists be shuffled and printed in same manner?

Following is the output:

[image]

seatCopy is shuffled but theatre.seats is not. Why ?

Comment: Please don't post images.   Provide output in your question in such a way that it is readable.

Comment: sorry! I will take care in future questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## A `List` holds references, not objects

Your `Theatre.Seat` objects do not actually live inside the list. A `List` holds *references* ([pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming)), memory addresses) to the objects. Each of those seat objects is actually floating around elsewhere in memory.

Imagine seats (compare it with objects) in various places in your home (compare it with memory). And imagine a cabinet containing many empty shelves, that cabinet being your `List`. Assigning a seat to the list is like attaching a piece of cord onto one of your dining table chairs while attaching the other end of the cord to the first shelf in the cabinet. Next, you attach your overstuffed TV-watching chair with another cord to the second shelf in the cabinet, assigning a second element to your list.

We say that the cabinet (list) holds two chairs (objects). But what we really mean is that the list holds two cords (references) that lead us to each chair (object). The other shelves in our cabinet without any cord are `null`.

When you copy the list (a shallow copy), you are not copying the objects. You are building another cabinet of empty shelves,  and then attaching a second set of cords. The various seats in your home are not duplicated. But now you have two sets of cords.

Answer (score 2):

They don't reference the same ArrayList.

They are 2 instances of ArrayList, both containing the same instances of every  elements.

So if you make a change on the instance of an element, it will be changed on both,
but if you do a change in the ArrayList, it won't change the other.

Answer (score 2):

Shallow copy of a list means that only the list is copied, but not the elements.
You do create a different list, but it contains the same objects.

If you were to do, for example

```
List<Theatre.Seat> seatCopy = new ArrayList<>(theatre.seats);
seatCopy.get(0).placeNumber = "13A"; // modify an element in the list(s)
Collections.shuffle(seatCopy);
System.out.println("Printing seat copy : ");
printList(seatCopy);
System.out.println("Printing theatre.seat : ");
printList(theatre.seats);
```

the modification of the element will appear in both printouts, but the order of the lists will be different (because they're different lists).